# Make changes to global variable in main script using another script without passing the variable as an argument

Tags: python, variables, global

I have two scripts. The first script is called `script1.py` and has the following lines of code:

```
import pandas as pd
import script2

global var
var = pd.DataFrame(range(10))

def add_column(data):
    data["New from script1"] = 1

add_column(var)
print(var)

script2.add_column(var)
print(var)
```

The second script is called `script2.py` and has the following lines of code:

```
def add_column(data):
    data["New from script2"] = 1
```

In both scripts, the `add_column` functions are exactly the same. As expected, no permanent changes are made to `var` when using `add_column` from `script1`, however, permanent changes are made to `var` when using `add_column` from `script2`. Why is this? See the outputs below:

```
   0  New from script1
0  0                 1
1  1                 1
2  2                 1
3  3                 1
4  4                 1
5  5                 1
6  6                 1
7  7                 1
8  8                 1
9  9                 1

   0  New from script1  New from script2
0  0                 1                 1
1  1                 1                 1
2  2                 1                 1
3  3                 1                 1
4  4                 1                 1
5  5                 1                 1
6  6                 1                 1
7  7                 1                 1
8  8                 1                 1
9  9                 1                 1
```

This leads me to my second question - Is it possible to declare `var` in `script1.py` in such a way that changes will be made to it if the code of `script2` was something like this:

```
def add_column():
    var["New from script2"] = 1
```

Comment: The two functions seem to do  the same. What difference do you mean exactly and what output did you expect to get?

Comment: I would like to under stand 1) why the function from script2 makes permanent changes to the variable, while the function from script1 does not. 2) Is it possible to declare var in script1.py globally in such a way that it is accessible by script2 without passing it as an argument.